# Incremental model update with PyMC3

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3, pymc

Is it possible to incrementally update a model in pyMC3. I can currently find no information on this. All documentation is always working with a priori known data.

But in my understanding, a Bayesian model also means being able to update a belief. Is this possible in pyMC3? Where can I find info in this?

Thank you :)

Comment: AFAIK, this is not implemented in PyMC3. Nevertheless you can do this _manually_, just use some data and prior, use PyMC3 to update to compute the posterior and then use the posterior as prior. You may want to ask this question [here](https://gitter.im/pymc-devs/pymc)

Comment: No, the major constraint is that after each update, you'd have to convert your posteriors to priors, before incorporating the next batch of data.

Comment: To clarify:
I want to build a model that predicts when certain events are happening. Whenever an actual event occurs I want to update my belief. Can I do this in pymc3? As far as I understood the library mostly supports MCMC and therefore does not really work with simple Bayesian updates or is it? I basically was trying to use the library because I can build complex models where for example multiple of my events share certain knowledge.

Comment: @ChrisFonnesbeck By "convert the posteriors to priors", do you mean using something like kernel density estimation and wrapping it with a Continuous subclass?

Comment: It's not always easy to do the conversion without loss of information, unless its a simple conjugate problem. It would be nice to be able to use a histogram or kde directly as a probability distribution; that would be the easiest, I guess. Note that the kde would inevitably mean loss of information in the transition.

Comment: In my opinion this would be one of the most basic use cases of a Bayesian framework in python. But maybe I just not really have any idea about Bayesians ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following @ChrisFonnesbeck's advice, I wrote a small tutorial notebook about incremental prior updating. It can be found here:

https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/docs/source/notebooks/updating_priors.ipynb

Basically, you need to wrap your posterior samples in a custom Continuous class that computes the KDE from them. The following code does just that:

```
def from_posterior(param, samples):

    class FromPosterior(Continuous):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.logp = logp
            super(FromPosterior, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    smin, smax = np.min(samples), np.max(samples)
    x = np.linspace(smin, smax, 100)
    y = stats.gaussian_kde(samples)(x)
    y0 = np.min(y) / 10 # what was never sampled should have a small probability but not 0

    @as_op(itypes=[tt.dscalar], otypes=[tt.dscalar])
    def logp(value):
        # Interpolates from observed values
        return np.array(np.log(np.interp(value, x, y, left=y0, right=y0)))

    return FromPosterior(param, testval=np.median(samples))
```

Then you define the prior of your model parameter (say `alpha`) by calling the `from_posterior` function with the parameter name and the trace samples from the posterior of the previous iteration:

```
alpha = from_posterior('alpha', trace['alpha'])
```

Comment: the notebook from the answer lives here now: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc-examples/blob/main/examples/pymc3_howto/updating_priors.ipynb