# How would you perform Bayesian updating with a normal-normal conjugate in R for single observations?

Tags: r, bayesian, normal-distribution

I am looking at performing some Bayesian updating for single sample observations (e.g. after every throw a quarterback makes). How would we calculate the posterior variance after each sample, where a sample is a single observation (n = 1)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53367519/570918). Because the form is closed, the code for updating is simple math.