# Updating a simple bayesian model with a set of new data coming in every 10 minutes in Python

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I am new with Bayesian Inference in Python and I wish to perform Bayesian updating with new data every time it is generated (10-min frequency). This means I will not perform it on a known set of data but update the model with singular datum every time. Unfortunately, I have not found any way of doing so with Python yet. Does anybody have a suggestion on how to proceed in such case? I was trying to use PYMC3 to set my model up.
I will be very grateful for any help. 
Kind regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incremental model update with PyMC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870840/incremental-model-update-with-pymc3) Also, [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211277/updating-model-on-pymc3-with-new-observed-data) has a particular implementation that takes advantage of a conjugacy.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It seems that in both of those cases, the users suggest solutions to quite complex problems. I was hoping to find a way to build the simplest possible model that would update itself every timestep. I am analysing a wind farm and its' data comes evevry 10 mins.

Comment: Consider adding an example of your current code to fit a single set of data. Without a proposed model, it's difficult to suggest an online updating strategy.